How to get time Series out of the charts made on Google Earth Engine Charts
From the Script i was able to generate charts which in turn i can download its Time Series. But this is a Long and Tedious task how can i make my script more efficient such that i can get the time series straight away. I am new in this domain so i am trying out things.
//Code Used by me

var startDate = '2018-01-01';
var endDate = '2018-06-30';

//var startDate = '2017-07-01';
//var endDate = '2017-12-31';


var images = imageCollection.filter(ee.Filter.date(startDate,endDate));


var scaling1 = function(image){
  
    var scaled = image.select('GMT_0900_PAR');
    return scaled.copyProperties(image, ['system:index', 'system:time_start'])
}

var scaled_nl1 = images.map(scaling1);

var dist1 = table2.filter(ee.Filter.or(ee.Filter.eq('NAME_2','Agra'),ee.Filter.eq('NAME_2','Aligarh'),ee.Filter.eq('NAME_2','Allahabad'),ee.Filter.eq('NAME_2','Ambedkar Nagar'),ee.Filter.eq('NAME_2','Amethi')));
var dist2 = table2.filter(ee.Filter.or(ee.Filter.eq('NAME_2','Amroha'),ee.Filter.eq('NAME_2','Auraiya'),ee.Filter.eq('NAME_2','Azamgarh'),ee.Filter.eq('NAME_2','Baghpat'),ee.Filter.eq('NAME_2','Bahraich')));
var dist3 = table2.filter(ee.Filter.or(ee.Filter.eq('NAME_2','Ballia'),ee.Filter.eq('NAME_2','Balrampur'),ee.Filter.eq('NAME_2','Banda'),ee.Filter.eq('NAME_2','Barabanki'),ee.Filter.eq('NAME_2','Bareilly')));
var dist4 = table2.filter(ee.Filter.or(ee.Filter.eq('NAME_2','Basti'),ee.Filter.eq('NAME_2','Bijnor'),ee.Filter.eq('NAME_2','Budaun'),ee.Filter.eq('NAME_2','Bulandshahr'),ee.Filter.eq('NAME_2','Chandauli')));
var dist5 = table2.filter(ee.Filter.or(ee.Filter.eq('NAME_2','Chitrakoot'),ee.Filter.eq('NAME_2','Deoria'),ee.Filter.eq('NAME_2','Etah'),ee.Filter.eq('NAME_2','Etawah'),ee.Filter.eq('NAME_2','Faizabad')));
var dist6 = table2.filter(ee.Filter.or(ee.Filter.eq('NAME_2','Farrukhabad'),ee.Filter.eq('NAME_2','Fatehpur'),ee.Filter.eq('NAME_2','Firozabad'),ee.Filter.eq('NAME_2','Gautam Buddha Nagar'),ee.Filter.eq('NAME_2','Ghaziabad')));
var dist7 = table2.filter(ee.Filter.or(ee.Filter.eq('NAME_2','Ghazipur'),ee.Filter.eq('NAME_2','Gonda'),ee.Filter.eq('NAME_2','Gorakhpur'),ee.Filter.eq('NAME_2','Hamirpur'),ee.Filter.eq('NAME_2','Hapur')));
var dist8 = table2.filter(ee.Filter.or(ee.Filter.eq('NAME_2','Hardoi'),ee.Filter.eq('NAME_2','Hathras'),ee.Filter.eq('NAME_2','Jalaun'),ee.Filter.eq('NAME_2','Jaunpur'),ee.Filter.eq('NAME_2','Jhansi')));
var dist9 = table2.filter(ee.Filter.or(ee.Filter.eq('NAME_2','Kannauj'),ee.Filter.eq('NAME_2','Kanpur Dehat'),ee.Filter.eq('NAME_2','Kanpur Nagar'),ee.Filter.eq('NAME_2','Kasganj'),ee.Filter.eq('NAME_2','Kaushambi')));
var dist10 = table2.filter(ee.Filter.or(ee.Filter.eq('NAME_2','Kushinagar'),ee.Filter.eq('NAME_2','Lakhimpur Kheri'),ee.Filter.eq('NAME_2','Lalitpur'),ee.Filter.eq('NAME_2','Lucknow'),ee.Filter.eq('NAME_2','Maharajganj')));
var dist11 = table2.filter(ee.Filter.or(ee.Filter.eq('NAME_2','Mahoba'),ee.Filter.eq('NAME_2','Mainpuri'),ee.Filter.eq('NAME_2','Mathura'),ee.Filter.eq('NAME_2','Mau'),ee.Filter.eq('NAME_2','Meerut')));
var dist12 = table2.filter(ee.Filter.or(ee.Filter.eq('NAME_2','Mirzapur'),ee.Filter.eq('NAME_2','Moradabad'),ee.Filter.eq('NAME_2','Muzaffarnagar'),ee.Filter.eq('NAME_2','Pilibhit'),ee.Filter.eq('NAME_2','Pratapgarh')));
var dist13 = table2.filter(ee.Filter.or(ee.Filter.eq('NAME_2','Rae Bareli'),ee.Filter.eq('NAME_2','Rampur'),ee.Filter.eq('NAME_2','Saharanpur'),ee.Filter.eq('NAME_2','Sambhal'),ee.Filter.eq('NAME_2','Sant Kabir Nagar')));
var dist14 = table2.filter(ee.Filter.or(ee.Filter.eq('NAME_2','Sant Ravi Das Nagar'),ee.Filter.eq('NAME_2','Shahjahanpur'),ee.Filter.eq('NAME_2','Shamli'),ee.Filter.eq('NAME_2','Shravasti'),ee.Filter.eq('NAME_2','Siddharth Nagar')));
var dist15 = table2.filter(ee.Filter.or(ee.Filter.eq('NAME_2','Sitapur'),ee.Filter.eq('NAME_2','Sonbhadra'),ee.Filter.eq('NAME_2','Sultanpur'),ee.Filter.eq('NAME_2','Unnao'),ee.Filter.eq('NAME_2','Varanasi')));

//-----------------------------------------
var chart = ui.Chart.image.seriesByRegion({
  imageCollection:scaled_nl1,
  regions:dist1,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(), 
  scale:250,
  seriesProperty:'NAME_2'
}).setOptions({
  title: 'PAR'
});
print(chart);

var chart = ui.Chart.image.seriesByRegion({
  imageCollection:scaled_nl1,
  regions:dist2,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(), 
  scale:250,
  seriesProperty:'NAME_2'
}).setOptions({
  title: 'PAR'
});
print(chart);


var chart = ui.Chart.image.seriesByRegion({
  imageCollection:scaled_nl1,
  regions:dist3,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(), 
  scale:250,
  seriesProperty:'NAME_2'
}).setOptions({
  title: 'PAR'
});
print(chart);


var chart = ui.Chart.image.seriesByRegion({
  imageCollection:scaled_nl1,
  regions:dist4,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(), 
  scale:250,
  seriesProperty:'NAME_2'
}).setOptions({
  title: 'PAR'
});
print(chart);


var chart = ui.Chart.image.seriesByRegion({
  imageCollection:scaled_nl1,
  regions:dist5,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(), 
  scale:250,
  seriesProperty:'NAME_2'
}).setOptions({
  title: 'PAR'
});
print(chart);


var chart = ui.Chart.image.seriesByRegion({
  imageCollection:scaled_nl1,
  regions:dist6,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(), 
  scale:250,
  seriesProperty:'NAME_2'
}).setOptions({
  title: 'PAR'
});
print(chart);

var chart = ui.Chart.image.seriesByRegion({
  imageCollection:scaled_nl1,
  regions:dist7,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(), 
  scale:250,
  seriesProperty:'NAME_2'
}).setOptions({
  title: 'PAR'
});
print(chart);

var chart = ui.Chart.image.seriesByRegion({
  imageCollection:scaled_nl1,
  regions:dist8,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(), 
  scale:250,
  seriesProperty:'NAME_2'
}).setOptions({
  title: 'PAR'
});
print(chart);

var chart = ui.Chart.image.seriesByRegion({
  imageCollection:scaled_nl1,
  regions:dist9,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(), 
  scale:250,
  seriesProperty:'NAME_2'
}).setOptions({
  title: 'PAR'
});
print(chart);

var chart = ui.Chart.image.seriesByRegion({
  imageCollection:scaled_nl1,
  regions:dist10,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(), 
  scale:250,
  seriesProperty:'NAME_2'
}).setOptions({
  title: 'PAR'
});
print(chart);

var chart = ui.Chart.image.seriesByRegion({
  imageCollection:scaled_nl1,
  regions:dist11,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(), 
  scale:250,
  seriesProperty:'NAME_2'
}).setOptions({
  title: 'PAR'
});
print(chart);

var chart = ui.Chart.image.seriesByRegion({
  imageCollection:scaled_nl1,
  regions:dist12,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(), 
  scale:250,
  seriesProperty:'NAME_2'
}).setOptions({
  title: 'PAR'
});
print(chart);

var chart = ui.Chart.image.seriesByRegion({
  imageCollection:scaled_nl1,
  regions:dist13,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(), 
  scale:250,
  seriesProperty:'NAME_2'
}).setOptions({
  title: 'PAR'
});
print(chart);

var chart = ui.Chart.image.seriesByRegion({
  imageCollection:scaled_nl1,
  regions:dist14,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(), 
  scale:250,
  seriesProperty:'NAME_2'
}).setOptions({
  title: 'PAR'
});
print(chart);

var chart = ui.Chart.image.seriesByRegion({
  imageCollection:scaled_nl1,
  regions:dist15,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(), 
  scale:250,
  seriesProperty:'NAME_2'
}).setOptions({
  title: 'PAR'
});
print(chart);


What collection are you using? Please share your code by clicking the "Get Link" button in the Code Editor so we can better understand your question.

var imageCollection: ImageCollection MODIS/061/MCD18C2
